# After updating iPad to iOS 8, WiFi no longer works

Tags: wifi, ios

I recently upgraded to iOS 8 on my iPad 2, now the WiFi doesn't work. I rebooted the iPad and router several times. Any suggestions?

Comment: many,so help us reduce them down to a answer, tell us about your WiFi settings? is it on! and scanning (showing networks)

Comment: Can you see the WiFi network listed under Settings > WiFi? If you can see it, can you join it?

Answer (score 4):

First I'd recommend you to reset your network settings:

Tap *Settings* → *General* → *Reset* → **Reset Network Settings**

If that doesn't show the new network within 90 seconds of leaving the device scanning for the network, next you might power down the iOS device once after the settings have been reset.

Enough users have the same problem as you see in the [official Apple forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6546549) as well as here, so it looks like Apple has changed how things work with iOS 8. *a.k.a “where there’s smoke there’s fire”*

So only "real" solution may be to wait for Apple to fix this with an update.

Comment: I've had to perform this reset on two devices and still iOS 8 seems to be "slower" to both release old SSID/network names when you move around as well as slower to recognize new SSID/networks when you arrive in a new location.